# compare two dataframes to see if they are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
db_data_df = data1['data']
data_df = data2['data2']
print(db_data_df.equals(data_df))
```

[image: .values]
[image: the two dataframes look like this]

I have two dataframes. I am checking if they are equal or not. They are. but instead of giving true, it is saying false. why?

If I turn the values of both df into dict this is the result I get.

{'data': {0: 0.88, 1: 0.976, 2: 1.072, 3: 1.195, 4: 1.295}}

{0: 0.88, 1: 0.976, 2: 1.072, 3: 1.195, 4: 1.295}

Comment: First, they look like series. They could be unequal due to "rounding" errors or small relative magnitude diff in your entries, you could use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html to handle that

Comment: Take care if you compare floating numbers.

Comment: it gave this error.. AssertionError: DataFrame Expected type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, found <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> instead @Learningisamess

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `np.close`:

```
import numpy as np

np.isclose(data1['data'], data2['data2']).all()
```

Comment: still gave False though the data is exactly same.

Comment: Without `all` and use numpy array: `np.isclose(data1['data'].values, data2['data2'].values)`. What is the result?

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Check if you have numeric types. `data1.dtypes` and `data2.dtypes`

Comment: both are float64

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `data1['data'].values` and `data2['data2'].values`?

Comment: updated the .values part with image

Comment: You compare a dataframe (2 dimensions) with a series (1 dimension). It's not possible, the shape should be the same

Comment: how can I make both the df to be the same shape?

Comment: Don't use image please! Update your post with the output of `data1['data'].to_dict()` and `data2['data2'].to_dict()` as plain text

Comment: updated as text

Answer (score 0):

It seems data1['data'] is series, while data2['data2'] is list. You can convert data2['data2'] to series and then use the same method that you used.

Try:

```
data1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'data': {0: 0.88, 1: 0.976, 2: 1.072, 3: 1.195, 4: 1.295}})
data2['data2']=[0.88,0.976,1.072,1.195,1.295]

db_data_df = data1['data']
data_df = pd.Series(data2['data2'])
print(db_data_df.equals(data_df))

#True
```